# Is there a way a relationship is automatically created when the nodes are created, given that the labels of the nodes already exist?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created two labels A and B with a relationship CONNECT. I need to create multiple nodes of of each label A and B and a relationship between them. i.e, for each node A and B, I need to create a relationship. 
e.g.: a1:A -[:CONNECT]-> b1:B, a2:A -[:CONNECT]-> b2:B,a3:A -[:CONNECT]-> b3:B, ... an:A -[:CONNECT]-> bn:B

Is there a way to create the relationship automatically? When I create nodes, can the db automatically create a relationship between the 
 nodes of different existing labels? Please help.

I used the APOC procedure to create multiple relationships between nodes manually on a property - for 100 nodes of labels LABEL1 and LABEL2, on a property value, I can create a relationships manually with a single Cypher query using below proc:

```
MATCH (ref1:LABEL1), (ref2:LABEL2)
WHERE ref1.property = ref2.property 
CALL apoc.create.relationship(ref1, ‘RELATIONSHIP_NAME', {}, ref2) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

But I want to know if a way exists, where a relationship between two labels A and B already exists; and whenever a new node of label A and B are created, a relationship automatically creates without running a cypher query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a relationship between 2 nodes created at the same time, just specify that pattern in your `CREATE` clause.

Here is example using `LOAD CSV` to import data:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data.csv' AS row
CREATE (a:A {x: row.x})-[:CONNECT]->(b:B {y: row.y})
```

Generally, it would be risky for a DB to automatically create relationships on your behalf since it might cause relationships to be created that you did not intend.

[UPDATE]

However, if `Label2` nodes are created at a later time than `Label1` nodes, and you are sure you want to automatically create the `CONNECT` relationship, you can use APOC to create a [trigger](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/61e72e1bbcd27c7b7a93dac63809a2d0f41b5188/docs/asciidoc/job-management/trigger.adoc) like this:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
  "create-CONNECT-rel",
  "UNWIND $createdNodes AS ref2
   WITH ref2
   WHERE ref2:Label2
   MATCH (ref1:Label1 {property: ref2.property})
   CREATE (ref1)-[:CONNECT]->(ref2)",
  {phase:'before'})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the above example, to create a relationship along with the nodes. But in my scenario, I'm gonna create a node of LABLE1 today, and might need to create a node of LABEL2 tomorrow, and I don't want to create the relationship explicitly.  -- the Labels and Relationships in my example are static. So, is there an approach that a relationship is created between the two nodes of different labels, when the second node of LABLE2 are created. Instead of explicitly mentioning the relationship?